# How to send SMS notification to customer after click on submit?

Tags: plugins, rest-api

I want to send SMS notification on successfull Appointment Booking. In this SMS i have to include customer name Appointmnet Date and Time.
My Appointment booking page is created with Elementor and here is the booking page link
https://jasdental.in/book-an-appointment/

Comment: What system are you using already to make the bookings? Does it support SMS confirmation? If not, do you have a way of sending SMSes already e.g. a service that you've signed up that you need to integrate with? Can you make that work from PHP, and you just need help hooking that into the appointment booking system? Or do you need help with something else?

Comment: You've tagged this REST API. Does the appointment get booked over the REST API, i.e. is the submit button making an AJAX request not a post back?

Comment: To send SMS you will need to use a third party API, you can look for SMS APIs for your country. There are usualy very cheap plans for those API. You need to take into account that you will need to write PHP code in order to send data to that api.

Comment: @Rup i had implemented my booking page with elementor

Comment: Oh, OK, Elementor has built-in appointment booking support? I didn't know that. Fine, so it sounds like you need to hook into the Elementor booking system, but I can't find any documentation for that at first glance. You might need to ask them for help finding the correct hooks to use.

Comment: Okay Thankyou @Rup

Comment: As Buttered Toast said though you'll also need a way of sending SMSes if you don't have one already. If the Elementor built-in booking support does already integrate with one that will be useful, else you'll have to write your own code to integrate with the service.